# Does .Net framework 4.6.2 installer support Windows 10

Tags: .net, frameworks, windows-10, .net-4.6.2

Does anyone know if the .Net Framework 4.6.2 Web Installer support Windows 10 or not. On [MS Website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53345), it doesn't mention Windows 10 as a supported version.

Thank you All

Comment: Sure it will, and 4.6.2 will come automatically with *Windows 10 Anniversary Update*

Comment: The web installer did not work for me! it finished installation without errors, but .NET framework 4.6.2 does not appear in the list of installed software! it also is not visible to Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

I tested it, and the web installer is supported by Windows 10 Pro.

And Net Framework 4.6.2 is part of the Windows 10 Update.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the .NET Framework 4.6.2 for developers, that one worked on my Windows 10 machine